# Check whether Azure Storage Blob is premium or standard

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

Is there an API or attribute available for `CloudBlobClient` or equivalent where you can verify whether the Azure Storage account is premium or standard when you have the blob uri and access key? I am currently using C#.

Here is how I am initializing the `CloudBlobClient` client.

```
var blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(
   new Uri("blobUri")), 
   new StorageCredentials("accountName", "accessKey"));
```

Comment: What are you planning on doing once you know this information?  It may help in answering the question (or providing an alternate solution)

Comment: They premium and standard storage accounts have different capabilities such as throughput so I would like to be able to dynamically differentiate from a large pool of storage accounts into 2 groups, standard and premium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the account type using management plane operations (i.e. using the [Storage Resource Provider](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage/4.0.0-preview) for non-classic accounts).

Assuming you do not have access to management plane APIs, one option is to use an API that is not currently supported in premium storage (such as attempting to upload a block blob). The request will fail on premium storage. However, be cautious with this approach as it is not guaranteed to work in future versions.

Ideally, your application could be designed in such a way that you automatically scale up to the capabilities of the account without knowing in advance whether it is premium or standard.